# Includes() not working, Receiving "Cannot receive properties of undefined (reading ''includes")

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, include

i'm following a tutorial on react and am creating a login page. When the user finishes writing their email, we call an onBlur(). As you can see on line 120 the onBlur calls the emailReducer on line 8, where the includes() command is run.

However I keep getting this error message (shown in this post's title) when using the include() command in line 11 and 14. I console.logged the action.val value in line 11, and it does exist.

I have an inkling it's a timing issue. Anyone know how to resolve this? thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';

import Card from '../UI/Card/Card';
import classes from './Login.module.css';
import Button from '../UI/Button/Button';

// made outside the component function: doesnt use any props defined inside the function
const emailReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'USER_INPUT') {
    console.log(action.val);
    return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.includes('@') };
  }
  if (action.type === 'INPUT_BLUR') {
    return { value: state.value, isValid: action.value.includes('@') };
  }

  return { value: '', isValid: false };
};

const passwordReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'USER_INPUT') {
    return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.trim().length > 6 };
  }
  if (action.type === 'INPUT_BLUR') {
    return { value: state.value, isValid: action.value.trim().length > 6 };
  }

  return { value: '', isValid: false };
}


const Login = (props) => {
  // const [enteredEmail, setEnteredEmail] = useState('');
  // const [emailIsValid, setEmailIsValid] = useState();
  // const [enteredPassword, setEnteredPassword] = useState('');
  // const [passwordIsValid, setPasswordIsValid] = useState();
  const [formIsValid, setFormIsValid] = useState(false);
  
  const [emailState, dispatchEmail] = useReducer(emailReducer, {
    value: '', 
    isValid: null,
  });

  const [passwordState, dispatchPassword] = useReducer(passwordReducer, {
    value: '', 
    isValid: null,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('EFFECT RUNNING');

    return () => {
      console.log('EFFECT CLEANUP');
    };
  }, [])
  
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   // start the Timer
  //   const identifier = setTimeout(() => {
      // setFormIsValid(
      //   emailState.value.includes('@') && enteredPassword.trim().length > 6
      //   );  
  //       console.log('okay im pretty sure ur done');
  //   }, 500);
    
  //   // can return, but MUST be a function = Called a CLEAN UP function
  //   // clean up fucntions ALWAYS run first before all other code in UseEffect
  //   return () => {
  //     // reset the Timer IF change was made
  //     console.log('CLEAN UP FUNCTION: reset timer')
  //     clearTimeout(identifier);
  //   };
  // }, [enteredEmail, enteredPassword]);
  

  const emailChangeHandler = (event) => {
    dispatchEmail({ type: 'USER_INPUT', val: event.target.value});

    setFormIsValid(
      event.target.value.includes('@') && passwordState.isValid
      );  
  };

  const passwordChangeHandler = (event) => {
    dispatchPassword({ type: 'USER_INPUT', val: event.target.value});

    setFormIsValid(
      emailState.isValid && event.target.value.trim().length > 6
    );
  };

  const validateEmailHandler = () => {
    // setEmailIsValid(emailState.isValid);
    dispatchEmail({type: 'INPUT_BLUR'});
  };

  const validatePasswordHandler = () => {
    dispatchPassword({type: 'INPUT_BLUR'})
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onLogin(emailState.value, passwordState.value);
  };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.login}>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            emailState.isValid === false ? classes.invalid : ''
          }`}
        >
          <label htmlFor="email">E-Mail</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            value={emailState.value}
            onChange={emailChangeHandler}
            onBlur={validateEmailHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          className={`${classes.control} ${
            passwordState.isValid === false ? classes.invalid : ''
          }`}
        >
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            value={passwordState.value}
            onChange={passwordChangeHandler}
            onBlur={validatePasswordHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <Button type="submit" className={classes.btn} disabled={!formIsValid}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispatched `onBlur` actions have no payloads:

```js
const validateEmailHandler = () => {
  dispatchEmail({ type: 'INPUT_BLUR' });
};

const validatePasswordHandler = () => {
  dispatchPassword({ type: 'INPUT_BLUR' });
};
```

But the reducer functions are expecting a `value` payload property:

```js
const emailReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'USER_INPUT') {
    return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.includes('@') };
  }
  if (action.type === 'INPUT_BLUR') {
    // action.value is undefined!!
    return { value: state.value, isValid: action.value.includes('@') };
  }

  return { value: '', isValid: false };
};

const passwordReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'USER_INPUT') {
    return { value: action.val, isValid: action.val.trim().length > 6 };
  }
  if (action.type === 'INPUT_BLUR') {
    // action.value is undefined!!
    return { value: state.value, isValid: action.value.trim().length > 6 };
  }

  return { value: '', isValid: false };
}
```

I suspect you meant to just validate the existing state when leaving an input, and for this you should reference `state.value` instead of `action.value`.

Example:

```js
const emailReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "USER_INPUT") {
    console.log(action.value);
    return { value: action.value, isValid: action.value.includes("@") };
  }
  if (action.type === "INPUT_BLUR") {
    return { ...state, isValid: state.value.includes("@") };
  }

  return { value: "", isValid: false };
};

const passwordReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "USER_INPUT") {
    return { value: action.value, isValid: action.value.trim().length > 6 };
  }
  if (action.type === "INPUT_BLUR") {
    return { ...state, isValid: state.value.trim().length > 6 };
  }

  return { value: "", isValid: false };
};
```